# What is the name for this: "x^^y" (as in 2^^2=2^2 and 3^^3=3^3^3 and so on)

Tags: notation, terminology, tetration, hyperoperation

How do you call / is there any specific name for the following:

**x^^y**

e.g.:

- 2^^2 = 2^2
- 3^^3 = 3^3^3
- 4^^4 = 4^4^4^4
- ...

Comment: superpowers, Knuth notation.

Comment: Look up "tetration:. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: Power tower or tetration springs to mind, also denoted $$^na,$$ where $a$ is raised to itself $n-1$ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), where $^na$ is $a^{a^{a^{...}}}$ with $n$ copies of $a$ in the exponentiation. You might also seen it written as $a \uparrow \uparrow n$.

To learn more about these kinds of compound arithmetic operators, I recommend reading about [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://plus.maths.org/content/writing-unwritable-arrow-notation).

Comment: Now that is one rapidly growing function!

Comment: @Mike :P More like some of the slowest of fast growing functions